# Longest monotonic subsequence algorithm NOT longest increasing algorithm

Tags: java, subset, sequence

I have some numbers at the input:

```
1 1 7 3 2 0 0 4 5 5 6 2 1
```

And I look for a longest monotonic subsequence and what is the sum of this subsequence. The result is:

```
6 20
```

I cannot find the algorithm at the internet. Do you own/found one? This is about longest monotonic not longest increasing subsequence.

Definition of monotonic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function

I know that someone will ask: What have you tried? So i tried writing it(**please don't check it I only post it so no one asks that question above** I look for different algorithm->optimal one)

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Rozwiazanie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            //2^63 > 10^16 = 10^7 * 10^9 longi starcza
            //10^9 inty starcza
            //int 32 bity, long 64 bity
            long podsuma = 0;
            int dlugosc = 0;
            int maxDlugosc = 0;
            long maxPodsuma = 0;
            int poczatekRownych = 0;
            int poprzedniWyraz = 0, aktualnyWyraz;//uwaga jakby cos nie gralo w sprawdzarce zmien typ na long
            boolean czyRosnacy = false, rowny = false;
            String[] splittedLinia = br.readLine().split((char) 32 + "");//moglaby byc " " ale tak na wszelki wypadek nie ma chuja zeby sie popierdolilo teraz nawet na linuxie
            for (int i = 0; i < splittedLinia.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    aktualnyWyraz = Integer.parseInt(splittedLinia[0]);
                    maxDlugosc = dlugosc = 1;
                    maxPodsuma = podsuma = aktualnyWyraz;
                    if (splittedLinia.length > 1) {
                        int nastepnyWyraz = Integer.parseInt(splittedLinia[1]);
                        czyRosnacy = nastepnyWyraz > aktualnyWyraz;
                        rowny = nastepnyWyraz == aktualnyWyraz;
                    }
                    System.out.println("akt: " + aktualnyWyraz + " pop: " + poprzedniWyraz + " dlugosc: " + dlugosc + " " + 1);
                } else {
                    aktualnyWyraz = Integer.parseInt(splittedLinia[i]);
                    System.out.println(rowny);
                    if (aktualnyWyraz == poprzedniWyraz && rowny) {
                        podsuma += aktualnyWyraz;
                        dlugosc++;
                        System.out.println("akt: " + aktualnyWyraz + " pop: " + poprzedniWyraz + " dlugosc: " + dlugosc + " " + 2);
                    } else if (rowny) {
                        rowny = false;
                        czyRosnacy = aktualnyWyraz > poprzedniWyraz;
                        System.out.println("akt: " + aktualnyWyraz + " pop: " + poprzedniWyraz + " dlugosc: " + dlugosc + " " + 3);
                    }

                    if (!rowny) {

                        if (aktualnyWyraz >= poprzedniWyraz && czyRosnacy) {
                            podsuma += aktualnyWyraz;
                            dlugosc++;
                            System.out.println("akt:" + aktualnyWyraz + " pop: " + poprzedniWyraz + " dlugosc: " + dlugosc + " " + 4);
                        } else if (aktualnyWyraz <= poprzedniWyraz && !czyRosnacy) {
                            podsuma += aktualnyWyraz;
                            dlugosc++;
                            System.out.println("akt: " + aktualnyWyraz + " pop: " + poprzedniWyraz + " dlugosc: " + dlugosc + " " + 5);
                        } else {
                            //  if (aktualnyWyraz == poprzedniWyraz) {
                            rowny = true;
                            //  } else {
                            if (maxDlugosc < dlugosc) {
                                maxDlugosc = dlugosc;
                                maxPodsuma = podsuma;

                            }
                            podsuma = poprzedniWyraz + aktualnyWyraz;
                            dlugosc = 2;
                            czyRosnacy = aktualnyWyraz > poprzedniWyraz;
                            rowny = aktualnyWyraz == poprzedniWyraz;
                            System.out.println("akt: " + aktualnyWyraz + " pop: " + poprzedniWyraz + " dlugosc: " + dlugosc + " " + 6);
                            //}
                        }
                    }
                }
                poprzedniWyraz = aktualnyWyraz;
            }
            System.out.println(maxDlugosc + " " + maxPodsuma);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
//65 87 47 5 12 74 25 32 78 44 40 77 85 4 29 57:
```

Comment: Use English in variable/class names.

Comment: "please don't check it" - why not? Don't you want to know if there are errors in it? What don't you like about your existing approach?

Comment: @Areo that is why I asked to do not check the algorithm. I said that I only post it so nobody thinks I've done nothing.

Comment: Algorithm is simple: You sum up next numbers until previous number is <= current number . If not then sum=0 and sequens-size is also 0.

Comment: You can't find an algorithm on the Internet? There's a **Wikipedia** article about the problem.

Comment: @NPE Then please post it because the wikipedia article is about longest increasing subsequence not MONOTONIC.

Comment: @Areo I look for monotonic not increasing subsequence.

Comment: @Yoda: Please make sure you add your definition of "monotonic" to the question.

Comment: @NPE There's a Wikipedia article about : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Rozwiazanie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String[] splittedLinia = br.readLine().split((char) 32 + "");//moglaby byc " " ale tak na wszelki wypadek nie ma chuja zeby sie popierdolilo teraz nawet na linuxie
            int aktualnyWyraz = Integer.parseInt(splittedLinia[0]);//uwaga jakby cos nie gralo w sprawdzarce zmien typ na long
            int poprzedniWyraz = 0; 

            long podsumaRosnaca = aktualnyWyraz;
            long podsumaSpadajaca = aktualnyWyraz;

            int dlugoscRosnaca = 1;
            int dlugoscSpadajaca = 1;

            int maxDlugosc = 1;
            long maxPodsuma = aktualnyWyraz;

            int czyRosnacy = 0; // 0 -- nie znane (jezeli w poczatku wszystkie liczby sa rowne), 1 -- rosnacy, -1 -- spadajacy
            boolean rowny = false;
            System.out.println("akt: " + aktualnyWyraz + " dlR: " + dlugoscRosnaca + " podsumaR: " + podsumaRosnaca + " dlP: " + dlugoscSpadajaca + " podsumaP: " + podsumaSpadajaca);

            for (int i = 1; i < splittedLinia.length; i++) {
                poprzedniWyraz = aktualnyWyraz;
                aktualnyWyraz = Integer.parseInt(splittedLinia[i]);
                if (aktualnyWyraz == poprzedniWyraz) {
                    podsumaRosnaca += aktualnyWyraz;
                    podsumaSpadajaca += aktualnyWyraz;
                    dlugoscRosnaca++;
                    dlugoscSpadajaca++;
                    rowny = true;
                } else { // rozne liczby
                    if (aktualnyWyraz > poprzedniWyraz) { // rosnie
                        podsumaRosnaca += aktualnyWyraz;
                        dlugoscRosnaca++;      

                        if (rowny) {
                            dlugoscSpadajaca = 1;
                            podsumaSpadajaca = 0;
                            rowny = false;
                        }       
                        if (czyRosnacy < 0) {
                            if (dlugoscSpadajaca > maxDlugosc) {
                                maxDlugosc = dlugoscSpadajaca;
                                maxPodsuma = podsumaSpadajaca;
                            }
                            podsumaSpadajaca = 0;
                            dlugoscSpadajaca = 1;
                        }
                        czyRosnacy = 1;   
                    } else { // spada
                        podsumaSpadajaca += aktualnyWyraz;
                        dlugoscSpadajaca++; 

                        if (rowny) {
                            dlugoscRosnaca = 1;
                            podsumaRosnaca = 0;
                            rowny = false;
                        }
                        if (czyRosnacy == 1) {
                            if (dlugoscRosnaca > maxDlugosc) {
                                maxDlugosc = dlugoscRosnaca;
                                maxPodsuma = podsumaRosnaca;
                            }
                            podsumaRosnaca = 0;
                            dlugoscRosnaca = 1;
                        }  
                        czyRosnacy = -1;
                    }

                }
                System.out.println("akt: " + aktualnyWyraz + " dlR: " + dlugoscRosnaca + " podsumaR: " + podsumaRosnaca + " dlP: " + dlugoscSpadajaca + " podsumaP: " + podsumaSpadajaca);
            }


            System.out.println("maxDlugosc " + maxDlugosc + " maxPodsuma " + maxPodsuma);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

what I had to change:

- you need a counter [dlugosc] (+ sum [podsuma]) for ascending 
  [rosnacy] and descending [spadajacy] values, as you need to count 
  both when the values are the same [rowny].
- I changed boolean "rowny"
  [equal] to int, as I thought that there are 3 values possible:
  ascending, descending or unknown. If there are several equal values
  at the beginning, there's all the time "unknown".
- this program needs at least one number, but therefore you don't need to check in every
  iteration of the loop whether i == 0 or not.
- Going through the
  numbers, I have to check several things, most important is, whether
  the actual value [aktualnyWyraz] and the last used value
  [poprzedniWyraz] are the same (then all counters and sums have to be
  changed) or different. Different can mean ascending or descending, so
  we have to increment the related counters and sum up the related sum.
  What happens the "opposite" variables? Well, we need to check whether
  the counter is bigger then the maximum one (so maybe these values are
  useful for the result) and then set them back to their start.